# How to get my account's balance using binance.net

Tags: c#, binance

Below codes purpose for get my balances using binance.net
but in console, just only "True" emitted.
How can I get my balance through c#?

```
namespace BinanceAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            BinanceClient.SetDefaultOptions(new BinanceClientOptions()
            {
                ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials("my_API", "my_secret"),
            });

            using (var client = new BinanceClient())
            {
                var balanceData = await client.UsdFuturesApi.Account.GetBalancesAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(balanceData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is returned in balanceData.Data

Your code should look like this:

```
        using (var client = new BinanceClient())
        {
            var balanceData = await client.UsdFuturesApi.Account.GetBalancesAsync();
            if(!balanceData.Success){
                Console.WriteLine(balanceData.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(var asset in balanceData.Data)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Asset: {0} | Balance: {1}", asset.Asset, asset.AvailableBalance)); 
                    // more info available in obj asset, just pick the ones you need
                }
            }
        }
```